# How can i get the path to an image file in wwwroot folder of an azure hosted asp .net core app inside a webjob

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

I am using an aspcore console app as a Webjob to send scheduled emails. In those emails i need to include an image from the wwwroot folder in the email headers. How can i get the url to that to pass into the src attribute of my img tag in the email html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test with txt file, to get the file path you could use `HOME` environment. It points to the `D:\home` on the Kudu. So if your file is in wwwroot, you could use the below code to get it.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot" + @"\test.jpg"
```

And the below is my sample code.

```
            string rootpath = null;

            rootpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + @"\site\wwwroot" + @"\test.jpg";

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxxx");

            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxx"));

            mailMessage.Subject = "message image test";

            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            string content = "If your mail client does not support HTML format, please switch to the 'Normal Text' view and you will see this content.";
            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content, null, "text/plain"));

            mailMessage.Body += "<br /><img src=\"cid:weblogo\">"; 

            AlternateView htmlBody = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, null, "text/html");

            LinkedResource lrImage = new LinkedResource(rootpath, "image/jpg");

            lrImage.ContentId = "weblogo"; 

            htmlBody.LinkedResources.Add(lrImage);

            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlBody);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            client.Host = "smtp.qq.com";

            client.EnableSsl = true;

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx");

            client.Send(mailMessage);
```

The below is my mail, and we could check the source code and find `src="cid:weblogo"`, this means the picture file is not a local file.

[image]

You could have a test with my code, hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks George for your answer.